# Increase Glassfish maxParameterCount

Tags: java, glassfish

I am developing a web based application using GlassFish 4 server. Today i got the following exception:

***WARNING:   GRIZZLY0173: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request ([10 000]) were detected. Any parameters beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.***

This means that when i did a post request to the server i sent more than the currently maximum allowed request parameters so i have to increace the value.

Anyone knows how this can be configured in case of GlassFish 4.

P.S. I dont want to decomplice the source files and change some value. I want to do it thought some xml configuration or throught the server administration console.

Answer (score 2):

In GlassFish 4 you can change the setting `max-request-parameters` with the `asadmin` command-line utility:

```
asadmin set server.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.max-request-parameters=10001
```

or manually in the domain.xml:

```
    <protocols>
      <protocol name="http-listener-1">
        <http max-request-parameters="10001" max-connections="250" 
           default-virtual-server="server">
          <file-cache></file-cache>
        </http>
      </protocol>
     // more protocols...
    <protocols>
```

Add the param `max-request-parameters` if it doesn't exist. Make sure to use the correct http-listener.

Comment: 10x but i have installed glassfish using the netbeans installation and i have no idea where this domain.xml might be. However i do have access to administration web based interface so i am trying to do the configuraton thought it.